# How do I click on a navigation bar item using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am fairly new in Selenium and I've been trying to work on automating the login for this [website], but for some reason `element.click()` on selenium does not seem to work when I try to click onto the Login button. I keep getting this `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` error.

Here's my code:

```
    try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH("//li[@class='item-119']/a[contains(text(),'Login')]")))
        )
    print("TEST")
    element.click()

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I've also tried using `By.CLASS_NAME` and `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` and I keep getting the same error. Spent a few hours researching, looking through StackOverFlow and trying to solve this error but I don't seem to be able to solve it. Please do help me and let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use wrong locator.
Selenium fails to find such element.
Also, it's better to use expected conditions of element visibility instead of element presence since when element becomes existing on the page it is still not clickable / visible.
So, please try this:

```
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='header']//a[@class='login-btn']")))
print("TEST")
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below xpath :

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH("(//a[@class='login-btn'])[2]"))).click() 
    print("TEST")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```